# Error while generating ApiDefinition.cs for Xamarin iOS Binding Project from Objective Sharpie

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, aviary

Steps I followed:

1. I have downloaded the Aviary SDK 4.0.1 from
   https://developers.aviary.com/docs/ios
2. I Created an iOS binding Project.
3. Renamed the AviarySDK file to AviarySDK.a
4. Added this file to the binding project.
5. Added the AviarySDKResources.bundle to this project.
6. Now as per the documentation for Binding Projects
   (http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_walkthrough/offline.pdf),
   I tried to generate the ApiDefinition.cs in ObjectiveSharpie, by selecting
   header files from the path
   "AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/"
7. This generates an error:

   In file included from /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:8:
   /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:17:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
   static NSString *const kAFProductEffectsGrunge = @"com.aviary.effectpack.01";
          ^
   /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:22:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
   static NSString *const kAFProductEffectsNostalgia = @"com.aviary.effectpack.02";
          ^
   /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:27:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
   static NSString *const kAFProductEffectsViewfinder = @"com.aviary.effectpack.03";
          ^
   /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:37:35: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'AFPhotoEditorProduct'
   @interface AFPhotoEditorProduct : NSObject
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^
   /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:44:39: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
   @property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *productName;
                                         ^
   /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:44:1: error: property with 'copy' attribute must be of object type
   @property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *productName;
   ^
   /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:52:39: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
   @property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *productDescription;
                                         ^
   /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:52:1: error: property with 'copy' attribute must be of object type
   @property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *productDescription;
   ^
   /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:64:39: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
   @property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *internalProductIdentifier;
                                         ^
   /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:64:1: error: property with 'copy' attribute must be of object type
   @property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *internalProductIdentifier;
   ^
   /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:16:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
   extern NSString *const kAFPhotoEditorEffectsIAPEnabledKey;
          ^
   /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:21:43: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
   @protocol AFInAppPurchaseManagerDelegate 
                                             ^
   /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:40:4: error: expected a type

   - (NSString *)inAppPurchaseManager:(id)manager productIdentifierForProduct:(AFPhotoEditorProduct *)product DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
     ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:40:152: error: expected ':'
   - (NSString *)inAppPurchaseManager:(id)manager productIdentifierForProduct:(AFPhotoEditorProduct *)product DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                                                                                                                        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:51:35: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
     @protocol AFInAppPurchaseManager 
                                   ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:62:72: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
     @property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                                        ^
                                                                        ;
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:62:73: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
     @property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:70:73: error: unknown type name 'BOOL'
     @property (nonatomic, assign, readonly, getter=isObservingTransactions) BOOL observingTransactions;
                                                                         ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:62:73: error: cannot declare variable inside @interface or @protocol
     @property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                                         ^
     1 warning and 18 errors generated.
     Error while processing /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h.
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFOpenGLManager.h:28:30: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'AFOpenGLManager'
     @interface AFOpenGLManager : NSObject
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFOpenGLManager.h:34:40: error: expected a type
   - (void)setPurgeGPUMemoryWhenPossible:(BOOL)purgeGPUMemory;
                                        ^
     2 errors generated.
     Error while processing /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFOpenGLManager.h.
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorContext.h:39:35: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'AFPhotoEditorContext'
     @interface AFPhotoEditorContext : NSObject
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorContext.h:45:41: error: unknown type name 'CGSize'
     @property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) CGSize size;
                                         ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorContext.h:48:60: error: unknown type name 'BOOL'
     @property (nonatomic, assign, readonly, getter=isCanceled) BOOL canceled;
                                                            ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorContext.h:51:60: error: unknown type name 'BOOL'
     @property (nonatomic, assign, readonly, getter=isModified) BOOL modified;
                                                            ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorContext.h:58:41: error: unknown type name 'BOOL'
     @property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL hasBegunRendering;
                                         ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorContext.h:75:26: error: unknown type name 'UIImage'
   - (void)render:(void (^)(UIImage *result))completion;
                          ^
     6 errors generated.
     Error while processing /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorContext.h.
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:14:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFEnhance;     /* Enhance */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:15:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFEffects;     /* Effects */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:16:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFStickers;    /* Stickers */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:17:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFOrientation; /* Orientation */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:18:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFCrop;        /* Crop */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:19:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFAdjustments;  /* Adjustments */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:20:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFSharpness;   /* Sharpness */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:21:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFDraw;        /* Draw */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:22:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFText;        /* Text */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:23:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFRedeye;      /* Redeye */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:24:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFWhiten;      /* Whiten */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:25:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFBlemish;     /* Blemish */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:26:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFMeme;        /* Meme */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:27:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFFrames;      /* Frames */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:28:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFFocus;       /* TiltShift */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:29:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFSplash;      /* ColorSplash */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:31:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFLeftNavigationTitlePresetCancel; /* Cancel */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:32:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFLeftNavigationTitlePresetBack;   /* Back */
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:33:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const kAFLeftNavigationTitlePresetExit;   /* Exit */
        ^
     fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
     20 errors generated.
     Error while processing /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h.
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:17:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     static NSString *const kAFProductEffectsGrunge = @"com.aviary.effectpack.01";
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:22:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     static NSString *const kAFProductEffectsNostalgia = @"com.aviary.effectpack.02";
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:27:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     static NSString *const kAFProductEffectsViewfinder = @"com.aviary.effectpack.03";
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:37:35: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'AFPhotoEditorProduct'
     @interface AFPhotoEditorProduct : NSObject
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:44:39: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     @property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *productName;
                                       ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:44:1: error: property with 'copy' attribute must be of object type
     @property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *productName;
     ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:52:39: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     @property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *productDescription;
                                       ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:52:1: error: property with 'copy' attribute must be of object type
     @property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *productDescription;
     ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:64:39: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     @property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *internalProductIdentifier;
                                       ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:64:1: error: property with 'copy' attribute must be of object type
     @property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *internalProductIdentifier;
     ^
     10 errors generated.
     Error while processing /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h.
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h:10:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
     extern NSString *const AFPhotoEditorSessionCancelledNotification;
        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h:16:35: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'AFPhotoEditorSession'
     @interface AFPhotoEditorSession : NSObject
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h:22:56: error: unknown type name 'BOOL'
     @property (nonatomic, assign, readonly, getter=isOpen) BOOL open;
                                                        ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h:27:61: error: unknown type name 'BOOL'
     @property (nonatomic, assign, readonly, getter=isCancelled) BOOL cancelled;
                                                             ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h:32:60: error: unknown type name 'BOOL'
     @property (nonatomic, assign, readonly, getter=isModified) BOOL modified;
                                                            ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h:44:51: error: expected a type
   - (AFPhotoEditorContext *)createContextWithImage:(UIImage *)image;
                                                   ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h:55:51: error: expected a type
   - (AFPhotoEditorContext *)createContextWithImage:(UIImage *)image maxSize:(CGSize)size;
                                                   ^
     /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h:55:76: error: expected a type
   - (AFPhotoEditorContext *)createContextWithImage:(UIImage *)image maxSize:(CGSize)size;
                                                                            ^
     8 errors generated.
     Error while processing /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h.
     sharpie-clang-parser exited with error code: 1
     System.Exception: sharpie-clang-parser exited with error code: 1
     at Sharpie.ObjC.Parser.Parse (System.IO.TextWriter sexpWriter, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 stderrLines) [0x00000] in :0 
     at Sharpie.Mac.MainWindowController+c__AnonStorey3.<>m__B (System.Object o) [0x00000] in :0

**Please can anyone help me?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trickiest step in getting Objective Sharpie to cooperate with the Aviary framework is to add an "extra clang command line argument" [1] on the first dialog window of Objective Sharpie. This extra argument allows `clang` to find and import the various Aviary header files as needed.

> [1] -F /path/to/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/

On the "Select Header Files" screen, you can then select just the "main" `AviarySDK.h` header file [2], and leave "Follow #include and #import directives" ON.

> [2] /path/to/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Headers/AviarySDK.h

Comment: Thank you Brendan, I have received your Email with the details :)

Comment: Brilliant!! A real life saver!

Comment: I'm attempting the same thing with Aviary 4.3.3 - have followed your instructions but get an error: fatal error: 'AviarySDK/AFPhotoEditorController.h' file not found
#import <AviarySDK/AFPhotoEditorController.h> - I don't understand the file is in the same location as all the other header files...

Comment: Any chance someone would share a working binding (iOS 8) so I don't have to reinvent the wheel?